# Question : Time Based Workflows

Tags: workflow, time-dependent-workflow

If I have a time based workflow triggered on Case create where I check if Status = 'Open' then close the case after 7 days.

Will the case still get closed after 7 days even if the staus <> 'Open'.  ?

I want to implement a workflow where the field check is evaluated again after 7 days and then the action is taken. Is this possible using a workflow or only via a apex job ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each time a record is saved, all rules are checked to see if they still apply. If not, then the delayed action is cancelled. In other words, it won't fire once the case leaves Open status, if that is how it is configured.